# How to get the Forgetten password of netsh wlan hostednetwork

Tags: cmd, wifi, netsh

I have created a hostednetwork using the netsh wlan set hostednetwork command  and i am  able to connect it  with my device. now i want to connect  my new phone with this  hostednetwork but i did not remember the password what i have been set.

I can set new hosted network   and connect both of my device with that network.  but i am curious to know

1. **Is their any way to know  what password i set ?**
2. **Can i reset password of hostednetwork ?**

Answer (score 22):

to display the password you used on your hosted network, type the command below on windows command line:

> netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security

Answer (score 6):

To view the security key content of your hostednetwork just open CMD with administration right and type:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork security
```

and press enter.

100% working.

Answer (score 4):

To reset your password on hosted network, run your cmd as administrator and you then type

Netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=new password

U can then confirm it by checking

Netsh wlan show hostednetwork security

Answer (score 0):

Hosted network settings are stored in windows registry. See at the key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSyc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings. The password may be there.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the simplest way is that reboot the computer, and reconstruct wlan network through the netsh command.